# Finding coefficeints of piecewise quadratic function in R

Tags: r

I have piecewise quadratic function as follows:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{3} a_i (b_i - x)^{2}_{+}$$

where `+` means that if `b_i` is greater than x, it is equal `b_i-x` else it is equal zero.
How can I get the coefficinets of the above piecewise quadratic function between zero and first element of `b_i` and then between first element of `b_i` and the second element of `b_i` and so on...

```
      a = c(1, 1, 2)
      b = c(1.5, 3.5, 4.5)
      x = sort(runif(100, 0, 5))
      mat1 = outer(b, x, ">")
      a1 = colSums((a * mat1))
      b1 = colSums(-(2*a*b* mat1))
      c1 = colSums((a*b^2* mat1))
```

I have written the above code for finding the coefficients of whole quadratic function

```
      f1 = function(x) (a1*x^2+b1*x+c1)
```

and I want to check the result with formula which shows that it is ok

```
      z = pmax(b - rep(x, each = length(b)),0)
      dim(z) = c(length(b), length(x))
      f2 = colSums(a * z^2)

      > all.equal(f1(x), f2)
      [1] TRUE
```

but I would like to find the coefficients of quadratic function between zero and first element of `b_i` and then between first element of `b_i` and the second element of `b_i` and so on.... How can I do this in R?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using restricted cubic splines?

Comment: why is the reason that I should use cubic spline? is there any benefit?

Comment: The methods are already developed and integrated with proper statistical inference?

Comment: could you please introduce that work to me?

Comment: I have been using the `rcs` function in rms/Hmisc with excellent results. Others have been using the `bs` function in the splines package.

Comment: Is the package name is rcs?

Comment: No, the package name is rms and that package is typically loaded with Hmisc.